# How do you find the sum of outputs

Tags: python, output

I'm a total newbie at python.  Anyways, I'm trying to find a way to sum the outputs of a program.  Obviously, when I do the program below, I get the numbers 1 through 20.  How do I sum these outputs together without doing it manually? (the sum is 20*21/2=210).

```
for i in range(1,21):
     print(i)
```

Comment: Did you try using an accumulator?

Comment: The time it took you to write this question could have been spent finding the answer 210 times

Comment: While many of us try to help, a little more effort on your part could have found the solution. It's really not that hard to Google this sort of question.

Answer (score 3):

It will simply be

```
sum(range(1,21))
```

Answer (score 3):

Either sum them manually in the loop:

```
total = 0
for i in range(1, 21):
    total += i
print(total)
```

or use `sum()`:

```
total = sum(range(1, 21))
print(total)
```